# Select com campo de mesmo nome entre duas tabelas sem ligação porem valores aproximados

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, dbase

Tenho as 3 tabelas, `users_teste`,  `nps` e `produto`, a tabela `produto` não tem relação com as outras 2 tabelas, Preciso realizar uma busca comparando a `solicitacao` da tabela `nps` com a `solicitacao` da tabela `produto` para fazer a contagem de quantos `produtos` o usuario possui e mostrar no nome de tal `produto`.

O problema encontrado e que no campo `solicitacao` da tabela `nps` possui o seguinte valor  `523dsagtjhtz`  e o campo `solicitacao` da tabela `produto` possui o valor  `523dsagtjhtz V-Gabriel`  visto que o inicio e igual e possível fazer um cruzamento e realizar o `select` desejado???

```
        CREATE TABLE users_teste (
              id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT unique,
              username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              cpf varchar(11) NOT NULL unique,
              permission varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              email varchar(200) NOT NULL unique,
              password varchar(200) NOT NULL,
              passwordResetToken varchar(200),
              resetarSenha varchar(200),
              dataCriacao datetime,
              idusuario varchar(200) not null,
              PRIMARY KEY (cpf)
            ) ;
        
        CREATE TABLE nps (
            id_nps integer auto_increment unique,
            solicitacao varchar(20) not null unique,
            notaNps integer,
            comentarioNps varchar(600),
            horaEnvioPesquisa datetime,
            horaRespostaPesquisa datetime,
            statusPesquisa varchar(5) default='0',
            telefone varchar(20) not null,
            nps_users_iden varchar(14) not null,
            primary key(solicitacao,telefone),
            foreign key(nps_users_iden) references users_nps(cpf)
        );
        
        create table produto(
        id_produto_increment integer not null auto_increment unique,
        dataSituacao datetime,
        status varchar(200) not null,
        recusas integer not null,
        id varchar(100) not null ,
        email varchar(200) not null,
        solicitacao varchar(100) not null,
        idproduto integer not null,
        titular varchar(200) not null,
        dataAprovacao datetime not null,
        situacao varchar(100) not null,
        validade datetime,
        nomeProduto varchar(100) not null,
        atendimentoExterno integer not null,
        produto_colaborador integer not null,
        primary key(id,status),
        foreign key(produto_colaborador) references colaborador(idusuario)
        );



 create table colaborador(
    id_colaborador_increment integer not null auto_increment unique,
    idusuario integer not null,
    usuario varchar(200) not null,
    colaborador_unidade integer,
    primary key(idusuario),
    foreign key(colaborador_unidade) references unidade(unidadeExt)
    );
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o operador `like` para fazer a query?

Comment: Sim, porem nao consegui, preciso realizar um count, o problema e que pra usar o like tenho que escrever um valor para comparar, quero realizar o count de todos as solicitações que esta presente na tabela 'nps'

Comment: tem como realizar um select e colocar um '%' na frente na condição like?

por Exemplo:

produto.solicitacao like (select .....)%

Comment: Pelo que entendi basta procurar a primeira palavra .. substr e suas amigas https://www.codigofonte.com.br/codigos/extraindo-o-primeiro-nome-em-um-campo-com-o-mysql

Comment: usar assim `LIKE CONCAT(NOME-DO-CAMPO, '%')`

Comment: Consegui utilizando  SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(solicitacao,' ',1),   para listar apenas a primeira sequencia  '523dsagtjhtz' e depois criei uma tabela temporária com os dados do select  e adicionei o campo como primary key, depois fiz outro select  entre a tabela desejada e a temporária.